# Page goes blank when working with database

Tags: php, mysqli

I am working on a form for a friend. When a user submits the form their IP address is added into a database table. Every time a user then visits the form I run a check to see if their IP address is already in the table. If it is then they have already submitted the form.

I did this previously but decided to change how it works and now when I got to run any queries or connect to the database the whole page goes blank.

Here is my database class (class.Database.inc.php):

```
<?php

/**
 * MySQLi database; only one connection is allowed. 
 */
class Database {
  private $_connection;
  // Store the single instance.
  private static $_instance;

  /**
   * Get an instance of the Database.
   * @return Database 
   */
  public static function getInstance() {
    if (!self::$_instance) {
      self::$_instance = new self();
    }
    return self::$_instance;
  }

  /**
   * Constructor.
   */
  public function __construct() {
    $this->_connection = new mysqli('localhost', 'MHP_TICKET_ADMIN', 'fZx_142n', 'MHP_TICKET_SYS');
    // Error handling.
    if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
      trigger_error('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error(), E_USER_ERROR);
    }
  }

?>
```

The code at the top of the form file (index.php):

```
<?php
require_once('class.Database.inc.php');
// Check database to see if the user has already submitted.
$user_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$db = Database::getInstance();
$mysqli = $db->getConnection();

$sql_query = "SELECT ip FROM ip_address WHERE ip = '$user_ip'";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql_query);
if ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    die('You have already placed your submission.');
}

?>
```

**EDIT**
I entered the credentials in the wrong order, and it took me 2 hours to figure that out...

Comment: Check your error logs. Also, what exactly did you change from when it was working to when it stopped working?

Comment: Oh no, just found the issue. In a hurry I entered the credentials in the wrong order...

Answer (score 2):

I know you've fixed this now (and I would comment, but I've not quite reached 50 yet) but for future reference this may help - an unexpected blank page in PHP most likely means an error is being thrown.

I make a habit of including `error_reporting(-1)` at the top of my script (in this case, your `class.Database.inc.php` file) so I see those errors immediately while developing and debugging. Switch this to `error_reporting(0)` when you go live of course to make sure errors are hidden from end users.

Comment: +1 from me. error_reporting(~0) is even better ;). BR.

Comment: +1 one thing I always forget is to add debugging help such as error_reporting.